How to fix: Unsupported font file extension: {ext}. add_font() used to accept .pkl file as input, but for security reasons
I have a python google cloud function that should create a pdf when triggered, but the code seems to breakdown, seemingly because of the font, see below.
I tested the workflow with my local installation of fpdf2 and everything worked fine, but it seems to be breaking up when I run it on the GC console.
The fonts are stored in a github repo.
Code below -
  class PDF(FPDF):
        import logging
        ....
        def header(self):
            ..........      


            self.add_font('Spectral', '', fname = repo.get_contents("Style/Spectral/spectrallight.php").decoded_content)
            self.add_font('Spectral', 'B', fname = repo.get_contents("Style/Spectral/spectralb.php").decoded_content)
            self.add_font('SpectralB', 'B', fname = repo.get_contents("Style/Spectral/spectralb.php").decoded_content)
            self.add_font('Spectral', 'BI', fname = repo.get_contents("Style/Spectral/spectralbi.php").decoded_content)
            self.add_font('Spectral', 'I', fname = repo.get_contents("Style/Spectral/spectrali.php").decoded_content)
.....

Here's the error I'm getting -
.......File "/workspace/main.py", line 378, in generation
    pdf.add_page()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 904, in add_page
    self.header()
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 217, in header
    self.add_font('Spectral', '', fname = repo.get_contents("Style/Spectral/spectrallight.php").decoded_content, uni = False)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1810, in add_font
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported font file extension: . add_font() used to accept .pkl file as input, but for security reasons this feature is deprecated since v2.5.1 and has been removed in v2.5.3

At first I used .ttf fonts from Google Fonts, I've also tried actually using plk fonts, now .php, but I keep get the same error.
I've also tried parsing the fonts with BytesIO, tried changing my fpfd2 to 2.5.1 (the function wouldn't deploy"...and a whole host of other fixes...
#======================================
EDIT:
I found the cause of the error; FPDF2 add_font definition
The add_font module checks if the string name (on the file path) contacts .ttf, which doesn't work if using requests or BytesIO to retrieve and parse the font.
This isn't an issue when testing on a local machine, but I need a workaround for a cloud function.
def add_font(self, family=None, style="", fname=None, uni="DEPRECATED"):
    """
    Imports a TrueType or OpenType font and makes it available
    for later calls to the `FPDF.set_font()` method.

    You will find more information on the "Unicode" documentation page.

    Args:
        family (str): optional name of the font family. Used as a reference for `FPDF.set_font()`.
            If not provided, use the base name of the `fname` font path, without extension.
        style (str): font style. "B" for bold, "I" for italic.
        fname (str): font file name. You can specify a relative or full path.
            If the file is not found, it will be searched in `FPDF_FONT_DIR`.
        uni (bool): [**DEPRECATED since 2.5.1**] unused
    """
    if not fname:
        raise ValueError('"fname" parameter is required')

    ext = splitext(str(fname))[1].lower()
    if ext not in (".otf", ".otc", ".ttf", ".ttc"):
        raise ValueError(
            f"Unsupported font file extension: {ext}."
            " add_font() used to accept .pkl file as input, but for security reasons"
            " this feature is deprecated since v2.5.1 and has been removed in v2.5.3."
        )


The error is clear that you cannot (continue) to use Pickle'd fonts with add_font but must use either TrueType or OpenType. Your question is unclear, your approach of using TrueType (.ttf) font files should work.

The iteration of the code I tested on my local environment uses .ttf fonts, but it still gave the same error about .pkl files being unsupported:
`self.add_font('Spectral', '', r'Style/Spectral/Spectral-Light.ttf' )
self.add_font('Spectral', 'B', r'Style/Spectral/Spectral-Bold.ttf' )
self.add_font('SpectralB', '', r'Style/Spectral/Spectral-Bold.ttf' )
self.add_font('Spectral', 'BI', r'Style/Spectral/Spectral-BoldItalic.ttf' )
self.add_font('Spectral', 'I', r'Style/Spectral/Spectral-Italic.ttf' )
    self.set_font('Spectral', "", 15)`


The code (using .ttf fonts) on my above comment worked fine on my laptop, but when I try to run it on the GC function it persistently produces that error.

It's difficult to advise. I'm unfamiliar with fpdf2 but I just tried a simple "Hello Freddie" function using Spectral-Regular TTF and the code worked locally and when deployed for me. If you can provide a minimal repro of the issue, we may be better able to diagnose your issue.

What is repo.get_contents?

@DazWilkin Thanks for the input. I found the root cause and it work perfectly. The issue was that requests.get().content did not provide a file name with the '.ttf' extension (see my edit), so I had to download the file and save it to a tmp folder with the .ttf extension in the filename, then use this in the .add_font function.

@AKX I'd used the github python api client to access my github repository. repo.get_contents() would fetch a specific file from the repo. I've resolved my issue though, thanks!
